# Avoid stale data from DB when using JPA?

Tags: database, spring, caching, jpa, eclipselink

I am facing a problem similar to the one described in [Invalidating JPA EntityManager session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400430/invalidating-jpa-entitymanager-session) :

**Problem: Getting stale data**

We are running JPQL queries on an SQL database that is also concurrently changed by a different application. We are using JSF+Spring+EclipseLink running under Tomcat.

The class doing the JPQL queries is a singleton Spring bean, and uses an injected `EntityManager`:

```
@Component
public class DataRepository{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    public List<MyDTO> getStuff(long id) {
        String jpqlQuery ="SELECT new MyDTO([...])";
        TypedQuery<MyDTO> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlQuery,MyDTO.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
[...]
```

*(code paraphrased).*

The problem is that this code does not see changes performed directly on the database. These changes only become visible if the Tomcat instance is restarted.

**What we have tried**

We assume that this behaviour is caused by the first level cache associated to the `EntityManager`, as described in the linked question. We found two solutions:

- call `entityManager.clear()` before invoking `createQuery` (this is suggested in the linked question)
- inject an `EntityManagerFactor` (using `@PersistenceUnit`), then create and close a new `EntityManager` for each query

Both solutions do what we want - we get fresh data.

Questions:

- Are these two solutions correct? Which one is better?
- In particular, can we safely call `entityManager.clear()` on the injected EntityManager, or will this somehow impact other code that also uses an injected EntityManager (in the same or in a different class)?
- Is there a different, better approach? Can we somehow declare that we want to refresh the cache, or that we want a fresh `EntityManager`?

I assume this must be a fairly common problem (as it occurs whenever multiple apps share a database), so I thought there must be a simple solution...

Comment: I think it's not very common to share a database with multiple applications? It sounds like you'll be punished heavily with constantly reloading your EntityManager. Can't you serve the required data through a service instead? Or use some shared cache between the applications?

Comment: @vertti: Good point. I did not realize JPA has such problems with using a shared database. Of course using a service or similar is possible, but it would mean a major change, and is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Creating new `EntityManager`s is correct, the other isn't (see below).
2. Calling [`EntityManager#clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) is very dangerous in all but a single-threaded system.

   > ...causing all managed entities to become detached...

   Hence, if one thread works with attached entities while "your" thread clears the entity manager you have severe side effects.
3. Hhm, hard to tell. If the number of entities modified outside your application is low I'd work directly with the datasource and a `JdbcTemplate` for the respective operations.

Comment: EntityManagers are not thread safe, so you should not be working on the same EntityManager in two threads anyway.  Each thread should have its own EntityManager injected, as they represent different transactional contexts.

Comment: True. Just looked at the OP's code snippet to make sure he's indeed using it that way.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, true. However, we use Spring to inject the EntityManager, and Spring gives us "a shared, thread-safe proxy for the actual transactional EntityManager" ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight ). So thread-safety is not the problem.

Comment: The link implies you are in a transaction otherwise the proxy uses a new EM per operation.  If this is correct, you might perform reads outside the transaction for better performance.  Also note EclipseLink has a shared 2nd level cache; verify you are using isolated cache settings

Comment: @Chris: Actually no, we are not in a transaction (I believe - the query method is not annotated @Transactional). Still we sometimes get stale data. I'm still investigating this...

Answer (score 6):

It looks like we have resolved the problem.

There were actually two problems:

1. While debugging the problem, in some cases we did not use a fresh EntityManager for every query. When using and re-using the same EntityManager, entities will apparently *never* be refreshed once they have been retrieved (unless refreshed explicitly using `EntityManager.refresh()`). This is apparently because once an entity has been loaded, it is stored in the persistence context (a.k.a. first-level cache) of the EntityManager. Doing this is necessary because the JPA spec requires that subsequent queries for the same entity return the same object instance. So in other words: as long as you use the same EntityManager, you will get stale data unless you refresh explicitly.
2. When we *did* use a fresh EntityManager for each query, things usually worked. However, we ran into [a bug in EclipseLink](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398067), where stale data is returned for certain JPQL queries (involving constructor expressions and JOIN FETCH).

**Short version**

If you want to always get fresh data from a database that is modified from outside your program, then

- use a fresh EntityManager for each query where you want fresh data
- disable the second-level cache (`<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>` in persistence.xml)

Answer (score 1):

To disable the shared cache in EclipseLink see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

Comment: We have already done that. However, the problem seems to be the first-level cache - as explained, everything's fine if we always use a fresh EntityManager, so shared cache is probably not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the magic
`entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(MyDTO.class);`