# JPA Lazy Fetch is not working when getting collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting a collection of objects and trying to get the object with LAZY loading in a @ManyToOne relation. But, when I calling the service method, my  object from the collection gets the NULL value

```
List<Location> all = locationRepository.getLocations(ids);
Merchant merchant = all.get(0).getMerchant();
// merchant == null
```

**LocationRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, String> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM b_location WHERE id IN :ids", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Location> getLocations(@Param("ids") Set<String> ids);
    }
```

**Location.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b_location")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "merchant_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private Long merchantId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Merchant merchant;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private boolean isActive;
```

**Merchant.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b_merchant")
public class Merchant {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "merchant_name", nullable = false)
    private String merchantName;

    @Column(name ="is_premium", columnDefinition = "boolean default false", nullable = false)
    private boolean isPremium;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Location> shops;
```

**What i was trying to do:**

1) Calling another query, example:

```
   @Query("SELECT l, l.merchant FROM Location l LEFT JOIN FETCH l.merchant WHERE l.id IN :ids")
    List<Location> getLocations(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

and

```
@Query("SELECT l FROM Location l LEFT JOIN FETCH l.merchant WHERE l.id IN :ids")
        List<Location> getLocations(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

and

```
@Query("from Location l left join fetch l.merchant where l.id IN (:ids)")
List<Location> getLocations(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

2) Changing FetchType to everything possible (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

3) Using

```
List<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);
// and
List<Location> findByIdIn(List<String> ids);
```

**P.S.**

When I'm getting only one object, it's working very good. For example:

```
Merchant merchant = locationRepository.findOne("11111").getMerchant();
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out my understanding of the underlying problem was not correct. Before the getting collection I was using locationRepository.save(location); operation. As it turns out JPA has a couple of levels of caching. My problem was solved cache cleaning using EntityMananager, for example:

```
entityManager.clear();
```

More info here:
[Invalidating JPA EntityManager session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400430/invalidating-jpa-entitymanager-session)

But as long as my question was not correctly asked, I suggest that Maciej Kowalski gave the wright answer. Thanks

Comment: You should change your query to "SELECT l FROM Location l ...". Your getLocations method returns List of Location entities

Comment: As for second option you have to do it in transactional method. Try to use some Merchang getter in this method -> locationRepository.findOne("11111").getMerchant().getId();

Comment: I think it is because of your custom query or method, but why don't you use `findAllByIds` https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAllById-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: @  alex valuiskyi Thanks. I appreciate your help ("SELECT l FROM Location l ..." and @Transactional). Unfortunately it still doesn' work

Comment: @Deadpool I have tried to use your comment (List<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);) but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Can merchant field be null? Try to add @ManyToOne(optional = false) and @JoinColumn(nullable = false). As far as I know it necessary to use Lazy loading

Comment: @alexvaluisky merchant field can't be null. I tried to set @ManyToOne(optional = false) and @JoinColumn(nullable = false). But merchant  gets the NULL value again...

Comment: Try this @Query("from Location l left join fetch l.merchant where l.id in (:ids)") I have similar repository method in my project and it works great. My entity has Long id.

Comment: @alexvaluisky I tried. I think, it should work, but it's not, and i dont know why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** You are using a native query here:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM b_location WHERE id IN :ids", nativeQuery = true)
```

No lazy loading will work in that case. The result object has no association with the Persistence Context whatsoever.

**2)** `FetchType.LAZY` is only a hint to the persistence provider. It does not have to make the association lazy, it may decide to fetch it eagerly.

**3)** In your case you do not even need a custom query. This should work:

```
List<Location> findByIdIn(List<String> ids);
```

Comment: In my version JPA i have only this method (List<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);. I have tried to use it, but it didn't work

Comment: You can declare method signature in you repository interface and use it. Framework creates method implementation

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi Thanks, but this option doesn't work also

Comment: @MaciejKowalski do you mean i should remove this (FetchType.LAZY) ? ))

Comment: No, it simply states that you may not achieve the lazy loading on an manytoany association.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Ok, I tried to use you answer, but it still doesn' work... or i can't understand what do you mean