# detached list from a query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to run a query, but the results should be read only. And they might need a refresh, and I don't want to refresh each element in the list. I'd rather re-execute the query. Thus I want all the results to be detached. What I currently do is

```
List<Ent> lst = (List<Ent>)em.createQuery("FROM Ent").getResultList();
for (Ent l:lst) em.detach(l);
```

But it seems wrong to me.

Any better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you do not want the returned objects to be managed by the persistence context .You can consider to use [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) as  everything returned using `StatelessSession` are in the detached state and do not managed by the  persistence context

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
List<Ent> lst  = session.createQuery("FROM DeviceTree").getResultList(); //All the returned Ent are in the detached state
```

Note that the `StatelessSession` does not implement a first-level cache , second-level or query cache.Everything you do results in immediate SQL operations . You can think it just like using plain JDBC, except that you get the benefit from mapped persistent classes .

---

**Reference**

- [The StatelessSession interface](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-statelesssession)

Comment: It's not exactly what I want, since I could use, say, query cache. But it's good more or less. Is there a JPA equivalent?

Comment: I am afraid there are no JPA  equivalent, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: BTW, this JPA is surely confusing. You expect `em.find(Ent.class,1);em.createQuery("UPDATE Ent SET data=17").executeUpdate();assertEquals(17,em.createQuery("FROM Ent WHERE id=1").getResultList().get(0).getData());` to pass. The fact that the entity is cached and not refetched from the DB is not completely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Hibernate doesn´t support the detach() method? You could copy your entities to a new object type and return these detached entities to the caller.

There are several similar questions about this topic here on StackOverflow: [Detach an entity from JPA/EJB3 persistence context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446/detach-an-entity-from-jpa-ejb3-persistence-context)

Comment: I already clone them. But when I'll execute `em.find(Ent.class,SomeIdAlreadyInEntityManager)` it won't be refreshed!

Answer (score -2):

Make the list as unModifieable list

### YOur code will be

```
List<Ent> lst = (List<Ent>)em.createQuery("FROM DeviceTree").getResultList();
lst =(List) Collections.unmodifiableCollection(lst );
```

### Sample

```
 List arl = new ArrayList();
        arl.add("sk");
        arl.add("sk2");
        System.out.println("...."+arl);
        arl =(List) Collections.unmodifiableCollection(arl);
try{
        arl.add("sk3");  // it will give exception
}catch(exception ex
{ex.printStackTrace();}     System.out.println("...."+arl);
```

Comment: huh? The user will still be able to change the entities! `lst.get(0).setData(12);em.flush();` will change the DB.