# What's the correct way to use hibernate with spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, integration

I recently started using hibernate and spring.

In the beginning I was told to use the sessionFactory and openSession together with beginTransaction to do db calls.

Later I heard about dao's so I started using it by creating an interface, implementing this interface in a class and then have this class extend HibernateDAOSupport.

I figured this was pretty solid until a colleague told me that this way is deprecated and that I should not use the HibernateDAOSupport class. But instead work with a SessionFactory instance in my dao implementation class and an instance of that class in a new seperate service class. Since this also seemed like a good way to do it, I decided to follow this path.

Just now I've read that this method is also deprecated with the new version of spring...
So my question is: What on earth is the correct up-to-date way to bring hibernate and spring together??

I've also heard talk about an entity manager, what is that about?

I'm looking for the general way to use them, if there are any exceptions to the general rule, please also provide an example of these exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one of many ways to integrate Hibernate into Spring...

Your Service (or DAO) class should look as simple as this:-

```
// annotate this class so that Spring is aware of it 
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // this is straight-up HQL... really, no magic here
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Collection<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Employee e order by e.lastName, e.firstName")
                .list();
    }
}
```

Now, you need to configure `sessionFactory`, otherwise the autowiring will fail. So, this is how you configure it:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!-- 
        When creating the session factory, point it to your existing hibernate.cfg.xml.
        You can also port your entire Hibernate configuration and HBM mappings here, but
        for simplicity sake, I'll reference the existing hibernate.cfg.xml here so that we 
        are not cluttering Spring configuration file with Hibernate-specific configuration.
    -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- If you are running in production, you will want to use JNDI connection -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp"/>

    <!-- If you are running testcases, you might want to use JDBC instead -->
    <!--
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://machine/myapp"/>
        <property name="username" value="myapp"/>
        <property name="password" value="myapp"/>
    </bean>
    -->

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.myapp..*.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice"/>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

There are two ways to configure transaction: 1) use `@Transactional` and you can annotate which classes (or specific methods) that require proper transaction handling, and 2) use AOP and wrap all your code with transaction.

In my example above, I'm wrapping all my code with base package `com.myapp` with transaction. You can change (or add) the pointcuts to reduce the transaction wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, one question though: You would use a service with a sessionFactory directly instead of using a a service that has a DOA which has a sessionFactory? Any reason for doing it this way?

Comment: It's up to you. I'm putting session factory in my service to simplify my example.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding Hibernate in Spring, as for 2013, HibernateDaoSupport is deprecated(and the HibernateTemplate too). It will not work in Hibernate 4.0.

I think that using [`@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) annotated classes with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` for Hibernate specific and `@PersistenceContext` annotated  `EntityManager` property to autowire persistence context for the JPA configuration is the current default choice.

JPA is a standard, while Hibernate is not, but most Hibernate specific things will work in JPA configuration(of course that would mean that you will not adhere to standards anymore and it will be harder to switch to another JPA implementation), only a few are available only in pure Hibernate, for example you could not detach standalone object from the session [prior to JPA 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446/detach-an-entity-from-jpa-ejb3-persistence-context). It's simpler to implement some new feature in a proprietary framework rather than to change the standard, but I believe that JPA 2.0 is suitable for the most of the cases.

There are a lot of similar questions on StackOveflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137974/difference-hibernate-3-5-jpa-2-0/) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770211/similarity-and-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernat) and so on.

A good argument to use JPA configuration is that it can work with [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) - a framework that simplifies implementing repositories(you only need to declare interfaces instead of keeping parallel hierarchies between interfaces and generic-repository based classes).